# Remove all metadata from an audio (Opus) file except for a few tags via CLI?

Tags: ffmpeg, metadata, tag

The few tags I want to preserve are: artist name, track title, date, album title, album artwork.

I can do this with MP4 files using exiftool like:

```
exiftool -all= -tagsfromfile @ -artist -album -title 1.mp4
```

But ExifTool doesn’t support writing to Opus.

Comment: What did you try thus far?

Comment: @vanadium exiftool has such options (`exiftool -all= -tagsfromfile @ -artist 1.opus`) but when i tried it it said "Error: Writing of OPUS files is not yet supported".

Comment: If you check [exiftool's Supported File Types table](https://exiftool.org/#supported), you'll see that exiftool does not include write support for opus files.  Or for any music/sound orientated files.  From the author's previous comments in the [exiftool forums](https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php), such support is very low on his to do list

Comment: Try `tagtrack` from the `audiotools` package. It has some healthy `--remove-xxx` options and it works well with opus files. http://audiotools.sourceforge.net/tracktag.html

Comment: @andrew.46 all the `--remove-xxx` options in tracktag are for removing individual predefined tags. No option to remove all tags/metadata, no option to remove custom-named tags.

Comment: @gom This tool: https://askubuntu.com/q/1405658/57576 (Disclosure: my own question and answer).

Comment: How about [Mutagen](https://mutagen.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)?  A 5-line Python script could do this.