# How do I build opustags on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)?

Tags: software-installation, compiling, metadata, tagging, ogg-opus

How do I build opustags on Ubuntu 22.04 Jammy Jellyfish?

opustags 
https://github.com/fmang/opustags

I am very keen to use opustags to *rebuild* my Opus tags. However it is not readily available for Ubuntu 22.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

opustags is not yet in the Ubuntu Repositories. Fortunately it easy enough to build from source as I demonstrate below in 4 easy steps:

**1. Assemble some build tools:**

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential cmake pkg-config libogg-dev
```

**2. Set a build area and download the source:**

```
cd ~/Desktop
mkdir opustags_build && cd opustags_build
wget https://github.com/fmang/opustags/archive/1.6.0/opustags-1.6.0.tar.gz
tar xvf opustags-1.6.0.tar.gz && cd opustags-1.6.0
```

**3. Build and install opustags:**

```
mkdir -p build && cd build
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..
make
sudo make install
```

**4. Testing, testing...**

Test your installation by running:

```
andrew@corinth:~$ opustags -h | head -n 1
opustags version 1.6.0
```

and along with `man opustags` you are right to go! opustags can subsequently be easily enough removed (if you wish) by deleting the following two files:

```
/usr/local/bin/opustags
/usr/local/share/man/man1/opustags.1
```

And now to clean up the tags in your Opus Ogg files :)